# ajaxify + history.js script loading issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Im currently using an ajax gist (found [here](https://gist.github.com/854622)) and it all seemed to be working great. However I then noticed that whenever It changed state, the scripts were not being loaded.
therefore leaving featured post sliders and music players (as the current examples) not working.

you can find the site at http://djbretthaley.j3d-design.com/

I am pretty new to the ajax and js side of things so excuse me if im slow :)

Thanks,
J3D